# PHP session with Chrome in subdomain different behaviour

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I hope someone can give me a clear answer about the following issue.
I use a challenge-response pattern for login. The login is on a sub-domain. Like subdomain.domain.com. Each time a user enters the login, a new challenge will be created and saved in the session (`$_SESSION`).

When I POST my form the response will be created and on server side check the response by creating the same match with the challenge which is saved in the `$_SESSION`.

What I dont understand, and how to solve is that when I enter subdomain.domain.com/form.php, the SESSION is set. I POST to the same page (and want to stay at the subdomain!) my SESSION is changed.
Running FF or IE it works without any problem, so value isnt changed.
But running with chrome it changes.

Further I found out that going via the link `domain.com/subdomain/form.php`, the SESSION isn't changed.

[Edit]
I checked the `session_id`, but that is the same.

Kind regards

Comment: You know that when creating a session, a cookie is stored on the users computer with the session_id on there which references to your session file on the server?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I only would prevent to get answers like, put your challenge in the cookie or something :-) But anyway, its so strange that FF and IE works without any problem, but Chrome revuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what a TERRIBLE bug was this...

However I found the answer.

I had a subdomain, I was only working on this, so it had nothing to do with sharing cookies or sessions or something like that.
But I had no favicon for the application! Chrome makes the POST action possible and searching for the favicon. When he cant find anything, he throw a 302 and bye bye, session is restarted...

So to be clear, you have problems with PHP and a session, only in Chrome? Check if you have a favicon set and check the network panel!
Many people respond also about the URL rewrite but the favicon is the problem...

Comment: it may not be chrome bug, chrome actually do the right thing. It tries to call your favicon but it is not in there, somewhere in your code there should be 302 redirection if not chrome simply returns 404 for favicon so before 302 your session variable changing. So there is no bug. There may be misusing.

Comment: @FZE it is only correct when I have the favicon in my source. But it is never set, so it should never make that call.